# Jenkins pipeline DSL Maven Error due to @tmp dir

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I just created a Jenkins Pipeline DSL job where I cloned a Java code from SCM and tried to run `mvn clean`. But the pipeline continuously throwing an error saying:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project>@tmp/durable-77d8d13c/script.sh: 2: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project>@tmp/durable-77d8d13c/script.sh: mvn: not found
```

Seems like it tries to find `pom.xml` inside the `<project>@tmp` directory which is empty. Actual code is cloned successfully inside the `<project>` directory. Below is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
node {
stage ("Clean Workspace") {
    echo "${WORKSPACE}"
    cleanWs()
}
stage ("Get Code") {
    git branch: "${params.branch}", url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xx/xxxxxxx.git'
}
stage ("mvn clean") {
    sh "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true"
}
}
```

I also tried with `${WORKSPACE}` env variable but still does not work.

Comment: You should use `withMaven()...{ ... }` pipeline part in Jenkins...

Comment: What makes you believe that `mvn` is installed on the agent you are executing on?

Comment: @mkobit I checked via `mvn -version` command against the `jenkins` user.

Comment: @JanshairKhan is that on the `master` or the agent you are running the script on? It is difficult to answer because the stacktrace seems to indicate that `mvn` is just missing from where you are running the build on.

Comment: @mkobit. I'm currently on a single master node.

Comment: Moreover, `M2_MAVEN` env variable is also set to `/opt/maven`.

Comment: @khmarbaise if use with `withMaven()...{...}`, I get the error `Could not find maven executable, please set up a Maven Installation or configure MAVEN_HOME or M2_HOME environment variable`.

Comment: Than you have not correctly configured maven in Global Tools configuration. The environment variable is not needed....

Comment: I configured maven in the Global Tools configurations as well to name `mvn` and `MAVEN_HOME` = `/opt/maven` as the value as my Jenkins host is Debian 9.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved, I modified the Pipeline DSL jobs by including Maven tool step as:

```
stage ("mvn clean") {
    withEnv( ["PATH+MAVEN=${tool name: 'mvn', type: 'maven'}/bin"] ) {
      sh "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing like that you can directly add `mvn` to path itself. for that, open your ~/.bash_profile and add these lines.

```
MAVEN_HOME="<path to maven folder>"
export MAVEN_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

Don't forget to do `source ~/.bash_profile` to get the changes. This will provide mvn to path so that you can access `mvn` directly.

So if you do that your code can be now like...

```
stage ("mvn clean") {
  sh "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message `mvn: not found` means that mvn command could not be found by Jenkins pipeline.

You should use a `withMaven` pipeline step to provide a valid maven environnement.

For example :

```
node {
    stage ("Clean Workspace") {
        echo "${WORKSPACE}"
        cleanWs()
    }
    stage ("Get Code") {
        git branch: "${params.branch}", url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xx/xxxxxxx.git'
    }
    stage ("mvn clean") {
        withMaven {
           sh "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true"
        }
    }
}
```

Check that Jenkins is properly configured to use maven (Under 'Manage Jenkins > Configure System') and the 'Pipeline Maven Plugin' is installed (Under 'Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins').

More information here : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin